# Enter and Exit events in UserForm with Frames don't occur as expected

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, userform

My user form has several frames with text and combo boxes in them as well as  text boxes between the frames. I want to be able to move through the controls using the Tab or Enter keys or by clicking with the mouse. By the first two methods the TabIndex and Cycle properties determine the next control, which can be in the same frame as the previous, in another frame or between frames. When using the mouse the sequence of selected controls is impossible to predict.

My research has shown that VBA considers Frames like sub-forms, where each can have its own ActiveControl. It follows that when the user switches from one Frame to another the ActiveControl in the first Frame remains active (retains the focus) within that scope, meaning its Exit event does not occur, even while the Enter events of the second Frame and the clicked control in it are triggered. However, the Exit event is forgotten only by the user, not by VBA. It will fire when another control in the same frame is selected - perhaps never.

When entering a Frame for the first time in a new form the control with the lowest TabIndex will take focus and become the ActiveControl. Its Enter event will therefore occur immediately after the Frame's Enter event. If the user now clicks somewhere outside this frame and thereafter returns to another control in the first frame, not the one that has retained the status of ActiveControl, the Enter and Exit events of the Frame´s ActiveControl will both occur before the Enter event of the clicked control, which will now become the ActiveControl.

Looking through my own posts on this forum concerning the same issue I realize that the problem has bothered me for years and others, too. The question is whether the Entry and Exit events of the frames can be harnessed let the Entry and Exit events of the controls in them fire at the time the user of my form expects that to happen.

**I intend to post answer to this question within the next half hour.**

Answer (score -1):

Here is the user form I used for my trials.

[image]

*Apologies: The TabIndex of Frame2 should be 4, not 3 as shown in the picture.*

And this is the code module of UserForm1.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Application.Run "Module1.ExitEvents", Controls(ActCtlName(Frame1))
End Sub

Private Sub Frame2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Application.Run "Module1.ExitEvents", Controls(ActCtlName(Frame2))
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    Debug.Print "TextBox1_Enter"
    PrevValue = TextBox1.Value
    DidExit(CtlIndex(TextBox1)) = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ExitEvents TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Enter()
    Debug.Print "TextBox2_Enter"
    PrevValue = TextBox2.Value
    DidExit(CtlIndex(TextBox2)) = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ExitEvents TextBox2
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Enter()
    Debug.Print "TextBox3_Enter"
    PrevValue = TextBox3.Value
    DidExit(CtlIndex(TextBox3)) = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ExitEvents TextBox3
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_Enter()
    Debug.Print "TextBox4_Enter"
    PrevValue = TextBox4.Value
    DidExit(CtlIndex(TextBox4)) = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ExitEvents TextBox4
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_Enter()
    Debug.Print "TextBox5_Enter"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "TextBox5_Exit"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_Enter()
    Debug.Print "TextBox6_Enter"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "TextBox6_Exit"
End Sub

Private Function ActCtlName(Ctrl As MSForms.Control) As String
    Dim Fun         As MSForms.Control
    Dim Ix          As Integer
    Dim Tmp         As MSForms.Control
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Ix = Ctrl.Controls.Count
    If Err Or (Ix = 0) Then
        Set Fun = Ctrl
    Else
        Set Fun = Ctrl.ActiveControl
        If Fun Is Nothing Then
            Ix = 10000
            For Each Tmp In Ctrl.Controls
                If Tmp.TabIndex < Ix Then
                    Set Fun = Tmp
                    Ix = Tmp.TabIndex
                End If
            Next Tmp
        End If
    End If
    
    ActCtlName = Fun.Name
End Function
```

The rest of the code is in a standard code module:

```
Option Explicit

' Frames & Boxes ++ 12 Jun 2023
Public TestForm             As UserForm1
Public PrevValue            As Variant
Public DidExit()            As Boolean


Public Sub DEMO()
    ' Frames & Boxes ++ 12 Jun 2023

    Set TestForm = New UserForm1
    ReDim DidExit(10000)                    ' see function CtlIndex
    TestForm.Show
    Set TestForm = Nothing
End Sub

Function CtlIndex(Ctl As MSForms.Control) As Long
    ' Frames & Boxes ++ 12 Jun 2023
    ' return a unique control ID between 1 and 9999 based on Ctl's
    '   TabIndex and that of its parent, if any
    ' Max 99 Frames/Pages with 99 controls each, indexed 0 to 98

    Dim Fun         As Long
    
    With Ctl
        Fun = .TabIndex + 1
        If Not .Parent Is TestForm Then
            Fun = (.Parent.TabIndex + 1) * 100 + Fun
        End If
    End With
    CtlIndex = Fun
End Function

Sub ExitEvents(Ctl As MSForms.Control)
    ' Frames & Boxes ++ 12 Jun 2023
    
    Dim Ix          As Long
    
    Ix = CtlIndex(Ctl)
    If Not DidExit(Ix) Then
        If (PrevValue <> Ctl.Value) Then
            Debug.Print "Exit code was executed"
        End If
        DidExit(CtlIndex(Ctl)) = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The payload goes in the line saying "Exit code was executed". It might take the shape of a Select statement, like, Select Case Ctl.Name, to apply different handling for the Exit event of each control. It is only the Exit events that require special treatment. The Enter events occur as expected.

My code determines the ActiveControl in each Frame and fires its event procedure both when the Frame is exited and the control itself. The Public variables PrevValue and DidExit prevent unwanted, duplicate, execution. DidExit works with the function CtlIndex which assigns a unique ID number to each control and flags it as having run its Exit procedure when this is so. PrevValue compares the value of a control on entry and exit and prevents action from being taken when there is no change (required when clicking on a control in a frame that is not the frame's ActiveControl).